Devise mailer not picking up
Mintest is generating an error
ActionView::Template::Error: Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
    app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb:5

hitting the auto-generated confirmation link
<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %></p>
Yet, development.rb has set default_url_options:
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }

What other motive(s) would generate this error?

What version of rails and devise are you using?
